# What apps for OS X exists to ease the writing of emoticons?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I want an application like [TextPics](http://www.textpicsapp.com/features.php) on iOS, but for use in OS X. I want to use it with chat programs, web sites (twitter, facebook, et al), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the application that I'm using is [Crazy Text](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crazy-text/id431122700?mt=12) it lacks the ascii emoticons, but so far is the better one that has the TextPics capabilities on OS X

Answer (score 0):

[Emoji](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/emoji/id448125777?mt=12) is the one that's gained the most notoriety.

Comment: I'm aware of Emoji but I'm looking at ascii emoticons